# JS AJAX removal fails

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

This code is executing correctly, but the problem is that I cannot get through to the controller so that it performs the deletion
JS- Runs without errors and no errors are observed in the Developer Tool.
But the controller itself is not executed.

**JS**

```
jQueryAjaxDelete = form => {
if (confirm('Are you sure to delete this record ?')) {
    try {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: form.action,
            data: new FormData(form),
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (res) {
                /*$('#view-all').html(res);*/
                setTimeout(function () { location.reload(); }, 1000);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log(ex)
    }
}

//prevent default form submit event
return false;
```

}

**Controller**

```
       [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> CategoryDelete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var category = await _context.Categories.FindAsync(id);
        _context.Categories.Remove(category);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Json(_context.Categories.ToList());

    }
```

**View**

```
              <td><form asp-action="CategoryDelete" asp-route-id="@c.Id" onsubmit="return jQueryAjaxDelete(this)" class="d-inline">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" />
          </form></td>
```

[**Developer tool**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnv3V.png)

**[SOLVED]**
You need to add routing through attributes [HttpPost], [HttpGet]

```
        [HttpGet("Admin/CategryDelete/{id}")]//here
    public ActionResult CategoryDelete()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost("Admin/CategryDelete/{id}")]//here
    public async Task<ActionResult> CategoryDelete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var category = await _context.Categories.FindAsync(id);
        _context.Categories.Remove(category);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return Json(_context.Categories.ToList());

    }
```

Comment: Is the JS being executed at all? Check the network tab of dev tools to monitor the request being made and to see what its response is. Also, set as breakpoint in your action to step through and see what happens. If there's no errors then either the AJAX call is not being triggered, or your call to `SaveChangesAsync()` is not working.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The AJAX code executes correctly but the controller doesn't even trigger. Added a screenshot of the Developer Tool

Comment: From your screenshot I presume that the AJAX call in the question is the top list item, '2', in which case your code is not being executed as the server is performing a 302 redirect when the request is received, before your action is invoked. That's a server configuration problem you need to investigate. The JS & C# logic in the question is not the issue.

Comment: If you try to set breakpoint on the code `setTimeout(function () { location.reload(); }, 1000);`,what `res` you will get in `success: function (res) {`?